# Game Hang on Launch with fresh PC, unique to 2 games, everything else works fine

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze, gaming, application-launch

I've been troubleshooting this for months because it's really annoying more than anything. I even built a completely brand new PC without reusing any parts just in case I had a hardware error. New Windows install and everything, nothing was reused.

This new PC literally has nothing on it aside from steam, the games, and the standard gaming stuff like nvidia's driver app, dx, etc. No third party programs at all. Firewall already configured to let everything through.

2 Games, FFXIV and Dota 2 randomly start hanging when I try to launch them. The task manager shows very low CPU usage (less than 1%) until it finally "catches up" and launches the games. This brings the CPU usage up to normal amounts you'd expect from a game running.

The longer my PC stays idle, the more of a chance there is for the game to hang on launch, but sometimes they hang when only starting the PC. Restarting the PC usually fixes the hang, or I can wait up to 10 minutes for the game to load.

The only similarity I could think of between these 2 games (since Dota2 launches through steam, but ffxiv launches independently of steam) is that they both run dx11. I've changed the dx version they run, even tried vulkan instead for dota and the lag remained. Other dx11 games such as witcher3 do not hang on launch ever. dx12 and dx9 games work as well, I've tried about 30 different games while these 2 were hanging and never had an issue. Furthermore when launching the actual games, there is no performance degradation, so they seem to run correctly once they actually start up.

I am rather tech savvy and this is the 6th pc build I've made, i usually am able to google every question, but this has eluded me. I even paid an independent tech support guy to take a look at my last pc and he couldn't find anything related to it.

There are no dump files or crash reports. The PC doesn't notice anything wrong in event viewer or the games' own debug lists. I have even tried resetting to previous versions of windows 10, but haven't had any results. I don't even remember when this started, likely around august 2018 if i had to guess, but it has been a while. My 3rd PC in my house is the one my gf uses and it is running very similar stuff and DOESN'T have this issue at all. Only difference i can think of is I use 21:9 monitor (single) for my pcs, but she has a single 4k monitor, all are connected with display port.

Nothing is overclocked, it's all stocked.

Specs [brackets indicate PC2]:

Windows 10 (updated to most recent update)

RTX 2060 [GTX1060]

i7 9700k [i5 8600k]

16gb RAM

850+gold psu

1tb SSD [200mb ssd/100mb ssd OS] (I have other hdd/ssd for other storage, but these are what the games/os are installed on)

1000mbps fiber net

Comment: So this issue popped up in destiny 2 for me too, and a new issue where it just freezes for a few seconds, then continues on like nothing happened. This occurs in dota as well.

Steps taken to resolve this so far to no avail:
Checked all drivers with driver easy premium, updated to most recent. Checked nvidia for drivers, updated. Reinstalled windows completely with a fresh install. Installed samsung magician to update SSD. Ran intel processor diagnostic tool, that was clean. Ran sfc scan short and long, fine. Removed and reinstalled all hardware aside from cpu. Updated windows to current

Comment: was able to resolve destiny 2 issue by setting nvidia control panel settings to maximum performance and turning on vsync to 144fps. I have no idea why default isnt maximum performance on that and why vsync helped, but the stutters went away. Found some related threads from 2013 on the dota issue that recommended I look at page failures and page file. I partitioned 100gb on my ssd and used it to create a giant page file. So far I haven't experienced any issues with this set up.